# Looping through dynamically generated checkboxes to get values

Tags: javascript, php, loops

I have a list of categories for products on my site and am trying to allow products to be listed under multiple categories.

When creating a product there is a list of categories with checkboxes generated from `PHP` like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$stmt = DB::run($sql);
$categoryCount = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($categoryCount > 0) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $category_name = $row["category"];
        $category_checkboxes .= "<input type='checkbox' value='$id' name='cat_$id' id='cat_$id'> $category_name<br />";
    }
}
```

I created a hidden input to determine the amount of available categories

```
<input type="hidden" name="cat_count" id="cat_count" value="<?php echo $categoryCount; ?>">
```

I am then trying to loop through these in `JS` to get which ones were selected to send via `AJAX` to my parsing script to add to the DB.

```
var categories;
var cat_count = document.getElementById("cat_count").value;
var i;
for(i=1; i<=cat_count; i++){
    var cat_id = 'cat_'+i;
    var cat = document.getElementById(''+cat_id+'').value;
    categories += cat+',';
}
```

I have two issues with this:

First a category can be deleted so although there might be 3 categories these could have ID's like '1,3,5'. So my checkboxes will have these ID's but the `JS` is looking for '1,2,3' and it obviously gets an error when it is trying to get the value of a `NULL` element.

Second, if it can get the values, it will get all of the values of all checkboxes not just the ones that are checked which is what I need. Although if I get a way to loop through the ID's correctly this shouldn't be too difficult to but in a `if checked` condition.

Any suggestions or assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stop fixating on IDs as “the” way to select elements (as newbies often tend to do), and use a common class instead. Select all elements with that class, then you don’t need to store the info how many you got any more in the first place, but can just use the `length` property of the node list that getElementsByClassName returned.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your comment, I'll try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CBroe for getting there first, that worked for me.

```
var categories = '';
var category = document.getElementsByClassName("product_category");
var i;
for(i=0; i<category.length; i++){
    if(category[i].checked == true){
        var category_value = category[i].value;
        categories += category_value+',';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cleaner way to do this. You don't need cat_count; Add a class to your checkboxes, select all of them, get their value and append it to the categories variable; Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andreiTn/LkkL9Lsd/)

```
var categories = "";
var checkboxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox"));
checkboxes.forEach(function(element, index) {
    categories += element.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Id need to be unique so this line `var cat_count = document.getElementById("cat_count").value;` will always return a single element.

Change it by adding `index` to it

Instead of Id you can use `name` with

```
document.getElementsByName("'cat_$id'")
```